# Invalid use of group function MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

So I'm trying to find the customer representative with the most revenue.
to do this i created a View:

```
CREATE VIEW employeeRevenue AS
SELECT E.EmployeeID AS ID, SUM(A.ClosingBid) AS Total
FROM Auction A, Employee E
WHERE A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID;
```

And then, I run a procedure over this view

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getBestCustomerRep()
BEGIN
SELECT E.*
FROM employeeRevenue RV, Employee E
WHERE E.EmployeeID = RV.ID AND MAX(RV.Total);
End
$$
```

and it keeps telling me that i have an invalid use of the group function.
I've tried adding GROUP BY and HAVING statements (but i don't understand why they would be needed in this case)

why doesn't this work?

Comment: Because you cannot place aggregation functions in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM employeeRevenue RV join
     Employee E
     ON E.EmployeeID = RV.ID 
ORDER BY RV.Total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Also, if there are multiple employees with the same max, then only one is returned.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! what a clever way to avoid using the aggregator in the Where clause

Comment: sorry i wasn trying to mark both asnwers as correct and wasnt sure as to how i could do that

Answer (score 0):

When using an aggregate function like sum () you must use a group by clause at the end of the query, try this in the view:

```
CREATE VIEW employeeRevenue AS
SELECT E.EmployeeID AS ID, SUM(A.ClosingBid) AS Total
FROM Auction A, Employee E
WHERE A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
Group by
E.Employeeid;
```

And you can use the aggregate function in the where clause as long as you place it into a sub query thusly:

```
Where e.employeeid = (select employeeid, max(total) from view)
```

Comment: Anytime mate. That can be used with an in operator as well, ie where employeeid in (select employeeid, sum(swag) as swagger, from employees where name like '%swagmaster%').. Hey how about accepting my answer? I think I get points or something for that right?